# is this Python 3.7.7 map/lambda expression buggy? the subcomponents work ok

Tags: python, lambda, map-function

Keeping this short by not getting into the application for now.
Here is my data: (list of numbers and strings)

`mylist=[20201209, 7100.0, 'paypal', 400.0, 'out', 'monthly', 'Paypal', 100.61676684696863, '']`

I need to convert this to a string of words separated by tabs where I have defined the tab size because I'm trying to print columns (using the wrap function in textwrap module. But my problem is before that stage).

this sub-expression works ok:
`lambda x: (x,str(round(x,2))) [type(x)!=str]`

But when I put it into a (listed) map function like so:
`list(map(lambda x: (x,str(round(x,2))) [type(x)!=str],mylist)`

I get this:

> TypeError: type str doesn't define **round** method

,as if it trying to parse str( as str.

I used that lambda format because it is easiest to read.
Using a more traditional format such as
`list(map(lambda x: str(round(x,2)) if type(x)!=str else x,mylist))` works fine. But lambdas are meant to be concise and I wanted to avoid those `if` and `else` keywords if I can. Perhaps this format is obsolete in 3.7.7?  The official docs are pretty arcane on this.

As for the application, the final expression I would be using is:
`c='\t'.join(list(map(lambda x: (x,str(round(x,2))) [type(x)==str],mylist)))`
   `wrapper.tabsize=2`
`print(wrapper.wrap(c)[0])`
This is from a list of lists that would make columns.
I'm still new at Python so if there is a cleaner way to do this feel free to let me know! (although doing it the hard way is good practice.  There might be a one-liner for this in some library.)

Comment: I wouldn't look for `one-liner for this in some library` -- first get it working, deploy, if too slow, profile and refactor. Don't start at the last step.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: {str: lambda y: y}.get(type(x), lambda y: str(round(y, 2)))(x), mylist))
['20201209', '7100.0', 'paypal', '400.0', 'out', 'monthly', 'Paypal', '100.62', '']

#  Hint: This solves your problem, but dont do this! Read on..
```

---

The point is, sure one-liners are great. Sure `map` looks compact (at least it doesn't over here). But prefer doing what is readable, maintainable and essentially simple.

I'd still suggest you to stick with your other version (modified slightlyto make it more pythonic):

```
result = [str(round(x, 2)) if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in mylist]
#yours = list(map(lambda x: str(round(x,2)) if type(x) != str else x, mylist))
#        ^ indented so you can compare which one is compact.
```

.. and please compare it with the monstrosity of the first line in this answer.

---

Lastly: `(something(x)) [type(x)!=str]` doesn't do what you think it does. It will fully evaluate `something(x)` (and this is exactly why you face the error), use the return value (`result`) and then try to something like: `result.__getitem__(boolean_value)`.

Comment: lots to chew on, thanks! I haven't had a chance yet to dig into list comprehensions much but it certainly looks cleaner and list comps. have been on my todo list.  Why